# How do i print out a number triangle in python? Using anything to string is not allowed. Only arithmetic operation

Tags: python-3.x, math

Example

```
n = 5
```

Output of each line is int type

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Comment: `for i in range(1, n): print(f'{i}'*n)`

Comment: @GhostOps they said that's not allowed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a math question, not a programming question (or includes multiple questions and is too broad).

Comment: No, it programming skill test questions.

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it.

```
for i in range(1, n):
   print(((i * (10 ** i) -1) // 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expect?

```
n = 5
               
for i in range(1, n):
    print(f'{i}'*i)
```

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is using the kind of string manipulation that's not allowed.

Comment: No, anything related to string is not allowed. Only math operations.